# Open Maps in Topology

Tags: general-topology

I can not seem to figure out why one mapping is not an Open Map, whereas the one is an Open Map. Below will be the following two examples.

In both examples, the the intervals inherit the Subspace Topology from $\mathbb{R}_{std.}$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the unit circle with Subspace Topology from $\mathbb{R}_{std.}^2$. Also, the function in both examples is defined as $f(t):=(\cos{2\pi t},\sin{2\pi t})$.

**Example 1:** The mapping $f:[0,1)_{std.}\to\mathbb{S}^1$ is not an Open Map.

**Example 2:** The mapping $f:[0,\frac{1}{2})_{std.}\to f([0,\frac{1}{2}))\subseteq\mathbb{S}^1$ is an Open Map.

I *believe* that **Example 1** is not an Open Map, since, for $1>\epsilon > 0$ the set $U:=[0,+\epsilon)$ is open in $[0,1)_{std.}$, however, $(1,0) \in f(U)$ and there is no open set around $(1,0)$ contained in $f(U)$. Though, I am not sure if this is correct, and I am not sure why **Example 2** becomes an Open Map.

Comment: In the case 1) the map is bijective. Every open neighborhood of $f(0)$ contains a part corresponding to $(1-\varepsilon,1)$, which is **not** true in $[0,1)$. In the case of 2) this behavior does not happen. Note that there $f$ is only open **onto its image** but not onto $\Bbb S^1$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re right about the first map. Let $S$ be the semicircle consisting of the points $\langle 1,\theta\rangle$ (in polar coordinates) with $\theta\in[0,\pi)$. The second map is open as a function from $\left[0,\frac12\right)$ to $S$, because sets of the form $\{\langle 1,\theta\rangle:\theta\in[0,\alpha)\}$ are open in $S$ for $0<\alpha\le\pi$.

This second map is just a homeomorphism from a half-open interval to a half-open interval that has been bent around into a semicircle. The first map fails to be open because the half-open interval $[0,1)$ was bent so far around that the open end now converged to the closed end, so to speak.

Comment: Thanks for the response Brian! One thing, did you mean to say "the second map is open as a function from  $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ to $f([0,\frac{1}{2}))$"?

Comment: @Dalton: No, I meant $S$; but it makes no difference, because $S=f\left[\left[0,\frac12\right)\right]$. It’s just easier to see that $f$ really just maps intervals on the $x$-axis to intervals on the $\theta$-axis of polar coordinates.

Comment: Oh, I see you defined $S$ to be the semicircle, I thought you were referring to $S$ as the unit circle. So, in essence, the first map is not an Open Map because the relatively open sets are "open arcs" on the circle, whereas the second map is open because there are open sets that include the point $(1,0)$?

Comment: @Dalton: Yes. $S$ is like a half-open interval, and $\langle 1,0\rangle$ has a local base of sets that look like (curved) half-open intervals with $\langle 1,0\rangle$ as endpoint.

Comment: Thank you Brian!

Comment: @Dalton: You’re welcome!